# how to sum only a specific row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having one table name student detail which containing following columns and data's

```
NAME   MARK2      MARK3      SID      MARK1  

Timmy  85         95         123        25


GSJD   75         95         25         69


FBKSD   88         75        27         96
```

i was trying to get sum the values of mark 1,mark2,mark3 for a specific row where mark1=96

SQL>

```
    SELECT mark1,
       mark2,
       mark3
FROM studentdetail
WHERE mark1=96(
  SELECT sum(mark1 +mark2+mark3)
  FROM studentdetail;
```

but its not working can you guys suggest me in this

Comment: ... Are you going to add another column when there's another grade to add?  This type of table design is probably going to cause problems for you in the future... especially since grades probably don't belong in a `student` table anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (mark1+mark2+mark3) as mark_sum 
from studentdetail 
where mark1=96
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql you can do like this:

```
select mark1,mark2,mark3,(mark1 +mark2+mark3) as Total from studentdetail where mark1=96;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mark1 + mark2 + mark3 AS total
FROM tbl_StudentDetail
WHERE mark = 96
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
select mark1 + mark2 + mark3 as totalmarks from studentdetail where mark1 = 96;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select mark1,(mark1+mark2+mark3) as total from studentdetail where mark1=96
```